# Return Switch case to main program in Java

Tags: java

I know this is an easy question, but I am new to Java and am so lost. All that is left to do in my program is output a message saying something like "Invalid input, try again" at the end of each case in my program if the user does not enter either a yes or a no and return to the point where it asks for another calculation. I know it's elementary and I looked for an answer the best I could but I simply don't know enough of the java terminology. If you could help me I would appreciate it so much!

P.S.It was pointed out to me that my variables should not begin with capital letters, I am aware and will not do it in the future.

```
    System.out.println(" The purpose of this program is to calculate the speed of sound through several mediums.\n The program user will input a distance in feet followed by a mediumd and the program will output the speed in feet per second and miles per hour\n");
    //declare variables

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    final double Air = 1126.1;

    final double Water = 4603.2;

    final double Steel = 20013.3;

    final double Earth = 22967.4;

    double OneFootPerSecond = .68181818182;

    double Distance;

    double AirSpeed;

    double WaterSpeed;

    double SteelSpeed;

    double EarthSpeed;

    boolean shouldContinue = true;

    while (shouldContinue == true){ 

    System.out.print(" What is the distance in feet:" );
    //ask the user to input variables


        while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble()){
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid numeric value, try again: ");
        keyboard.next();
        }
        Distance =keyboard.nextDouble();
        {
        System.out.print("Input the media: Air, Water, Steel, or Earth: ");
        String Input = keyboard.next();   



        switch(Input.toLowerCase())

         {

            case "air":
            AirSpeed = Distance/Air;
            System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through AIR" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Air);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            String Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();
           if (Another.equals("no")){
               shouldContinue = false;
                              }
          if (!Another.equals("no"))
              if (!Another.equals("yes"))
              {System.out.print("Invalid.");


              }


            break;



     case "water":
            WaterSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through WATER" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",WaterSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond*Water);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();
             if (Another.equals("yes")){
               shouldContinue = false;

           }
    break;

     case "steel":
            SteelSpeed = Distance/Steel;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through STEEL" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",SteelSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f",  OneFootPerSecond*Steel);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();
             if (Another.equals("yes")){
               shouldContinue = false;

           }
    break;     

          case "earth":
            EarthSpeed = Distance/Water;
            System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
            System.out.print(Distance);
            System.out.print(" feet through EARTH" +"\n");
            System.out.printf("%.6f",EarthSpeed);
            System.out.print(" seconds or ");
            System.out.printf("%.1f",  OneFootPerSecond*Earth);
            System.out.print(" miles per hour."); 
            System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
            Another = keyboard.next();
            Another.toLowerCase();
             if (Another.equals("yes")){
               shouldContinue = false;

           }
    break;
    default :
            System.out.print("Invalid. Re-run the program. ");                  
     break;                      
        }
       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you want to ask for another calculation for every case, to prevent duplicated code move the prompt for additional processing out of the cases and put it after the switch statement. Then provide a method to continue prompting the user until they enter acceptable input.

```
    public boolean promptForContinue(final Scanner keyboard) {
    boolean isValid = false;
    String userInput = "";
    do {
        userInput = keyboard.next();

        isValid = userInput.matches("Yes|No");

        if (!isValid) {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry.");
        }
    } while (!isValid);

    return userInput.equals("Yes") ? true : false;
}
```

**EDIT**: Alternative implementation removing the need for extra local variables and removing the usage of `regex`. Also, the addition of `.toLowerCase()` expands the acceptable input without the need of additional `case` statements. For this simple use case, we can take advantage of the `fall through` effect of case statements to expand  acceptable values to 8.

```
 private static boolean promptForContinue(final Scanner keyboard)
 {
    do
    {
     System.out.print("Continue (Yes/No) ?");
     final String userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();

     switch(userInput)
     {
       case "y":
       case "yes": return true;
       case "n": 
       case "no": return false;
       default : 
         System.out.println("Invalid Entry.");
     }
   }
   while (true);
 }
```

Then shouldContinue would be set to the return value of that method in the end of your while loop.

```
shouldContinue = promptForContinue(keyboard);
```

Incorporating what you had with my suggestion the file should look something like the following. Also, I would suggest storing both calculations in a variable so that you could move the duplicated print statements out of the cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
System.out.println(" The purpose of this program is to calculate the speed of sound through several mediums.\n The program user will input a distance in feet followed by a mediumd and the program will output the speed in feet per second and miles per hour\n");
//declare variables

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

final double Air = 1126.1;

final double Water = 4603.2;

final double Steel = 20013.3;

final double Earth = 22967.4;

double OneFootPerSecond = .68181818182;

double Distance;

double AirSpeed;

double WaterSpeed;

double SteelSpeed;

double EarthSpeed;

boolean shouldContinue = true;

while (shouldContinue == true)
{

  System.out.print(" What is the distance in feet:");
  //ask the user to input variables


  while (!keyboard.hasNextDouble())
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid numeric value, try again: ");
    keyboard.next();
  }

  Distance = keyboard.nextDouble();

  System.out.print("Input the media: Air, Water, Steel, or Earth: ");
  String Input = keyboard.next();

  switch (Input.toLowerCase())
  {

    case "air":
      AirSpeed = Distance / Air;
      System.out.print("\n \nThe time to for sound to travel ");
      System.out.print(Distance);
      System.out.print(" feet through AIR" + "\n");
      System.out.printf("%.6f", AirSpeed);
      System.out.print(" seconds or ");
      System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond * Air);
      System.out.println(" miles per hour.");

      break;

    case "water":
      WaterSpeed = Distance / Water;
      System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
      System.out.print(Distance);
      System.out.print(" feet through WATER" + "\n");
      System.out.printf("%.6f", WaterSpeed);
      System.out.print(" seconds or ");
      System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond * Water);
      System.out.println(" miles per hour.");

      break;

    case "steel":
      SteelSpeed = Distance / Steel;
      System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
      System.out.print(Distance);
      System.out.print(" feet through STEEL" + "\n");
      System.out.printf("%.6f", SteelSpeed);
      System.out.print(" seconds or ");
      System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond * Steel);
      System.out.println(" miles per hour.");


      break;

    case "earth":
      EarthSpeed = Distance / Water;
      System.out.print("\nThe time to for sound to travel ");
      System.out.print(Distance);
      System.out.print(" feet through EARTH" + "\n");
      System.out.printf("%.6f", EarthSpeed);
      System.out.print(" seconds or ");
      System.out.printf("%.1f", OneFootPerSecond * Earth);
      System.out.println(" miles per hour.");

      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Invalid. Re-run the program. ");
      break;
  }
  shouldContinue = promptForContinue(keyboard);
 }

}

private static boolean promptForContinue(final Scanner keyboard)
{
 boolean isValid = false;
 String userInput = "";
 do
 {
   System.out.print("Continue (Yes/No) ?");
   userInput = keyboard.next();

   isValid = userInput.matches("Yes|No");

   if (!isValid)
   {
    System.out.println("\nInvalid entry.");
   }
 }
 while (!isValid);

 return userInput.equals("Yes") ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I tried you suggestions but I got multiple errors. illegal start of an expression for the public boolean, cannot find symbol for while (!isValid) and expected ; right after (!isValid). I can't imagine the solution is difficult, I just need to return to the part of the program that asks for another calculation if yes or no isnt inputted. I'm going crazy :(

Comment: My apologies...threw it together quickly without testing it due my multitasking. Should be good now.

Comment: Everything looks to be correct except for at the public boolean,  I get illegal start of an expression. I am probably incorrect, but does that have anything to do with the public static void main?

Comment: make it private static and ensure it is outside the method definition of main

Comment: Fixed and fully functional! I cannot thank you sir (or ma'am) enough, I have been trying to figure that out for far too long! You saved me some possible gray hairs ;). But on a serious note, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic problem

```
        System.out.print("\n \nEnter Yes for another calculation, else No: ");
        Another = keyboard.next();
        Another.toLowerCase();
         if (Another.equals("yes")){
           shouldContinue = false;

       }
```

this code is going to exit the loop if the user type yes, your if should be something like:

```
        if (Another.equals("yes")){
           shouldContinue = true;

       }
       else 
       if (Another.equals("no")){
           shouldContinue = false;

       }
       else 
       {
           System.out.print("Invalid input");
           shouldContinue = true;

       }
```